# mongoose difference of findOneAndUpdate and update

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, sql-update

What is the difference between findOneAndUpdate and update?

Both accept criteria to query and doc to update.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Well there is the respective documentation to view for both [**`.update()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) and [**`.findAndModify()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/) which is the root method of `.findOneAndUpdate()` here.

But in the main differences there are:

- **update()**: Is meant to perform an atomic update operation against "one or more" documents matched by it's query condition in a collection. It returns the number of modified documents in it's response.
- **findOneAndUpdate()**: Has the purpose of both processing an update statment on a "singular" document, as well as retrieving the content of that "singular" document. The state returned depends on the value of the "new" option as passed to the operation. Where `true` the "modified" document is returned. Where `false` the "original" document is returned before any modification. The latter form is the default option.

In short. One is meant to modify in "bulk" and not worry with the document content in result. And the other is meant to modify a singular document and return the document content in result.

That's the difference.

Comment: The question would have been more consistent as follows: What's the difference between mongoDB 'findOneAndUpdate' and 'updateOne', or/and What's the difference between mongoDB 'update' and 'findAndModify'. Performance?

Comment: One additional difference: when using Mongoose middleware (hooks), `updateOne` triggers a document middleware, and `findOneAndUpdate` triggers a query middleware. Both differ on what data is accessible when coding the hook (the document in the former, the query in the latter).

Answer (score 6):

The [`.findOneAndUpdate`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndUpdate) method issues a mongodb [`.findAndModify`](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/findAndModify+Command) update command  and returns the found document (if any) to the callback or return the modified document rather than the original if the `new` option is `true` and the [`.update`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-update) execute the query as an [`update()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) operation.

Answer (score 2):

Note there is an option `returnNewDocument` in the findOneAndXXX methods and it's default value is `true`. If you are using the node.js driver, the options is called `returnOriginal`.