# Differences between find_one_and_update() and update_one() in PyMongo for MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

Here are the references for:

- [`find_one_and_update`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find_one_and_update) method

> Finds a single document and updates it, returning either the original or the updated document.

- [`update_one`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update_one) method

> Update a single document matching the filter.

It seems to me both of them first query the selected document, then update it.

I would like to know if there is some kind of optimization difference. The only other difference is in the return value, which makes me wonder why one would even use `update_one()` at all.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36209434/248296

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are some changes between that two operations:

- `find_one_and_update`

> By default :meth:`find_one_and_update` returns the original version of
>           the document before the update was applied. To return the updated
>           version of the document instead, use the *return_document* option.
>
> You can limit the fields returned with the *projection* option.
>
> The *upsert* option can be used to create the document if it doesn't
>           already exist.
>
> If multiple documents match *filter*, a *sort* can be applied.

So this method do a kind of `find` operation that allows you to sort and filter records in your database.

- `update_one`

With this method you can't sort your records, it just does a `find` operation and update each found elements with a `for` cycle.

So at the end i think the `update_one` operation is *faster* than the `find_one_and_update` operation.