# Pushing a new object doesn't gets retuned in the callback

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**Before marking it as a duplicate:**
Read further carefully, I'm trying to update the DOC from the DOC itself. Not using a SCHEMA or MODEL. Therefore, any .findById* goes right out the window.

Here's what my schema currently looks like (only the related section):

```
let UserAccSchema = new Schema({
meta : {
accessControl: {
authTokens:[{
    issuedOn: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now()
    },
    expiresOn: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now() + 1728000000 //Defaults to 20-days
    },
    lastUsage: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now()
    },
    authAgent: {
        type: String,
        default: "default"
    }
}]}}
});
```

I want to push a new object in "meta/accessControl/authTokens". My current approach is:

```
UserAccSchema.methods.generateAuthToken = function (authAgent, cb) {
    console.info("MongoUser | Auth | Attempting to generate auth token for user | " + this._id);
    this.update({
        $push: {
            "meta.accessControl.authTokens": {
                authAgent: authAgent
            }
        }
    }, {safe: true, new: true, upsert:true}, function (err, obj) {
        if (err) {
            console.error("MongoUser | Auth | Error occurred while saving auth-token information | " + err);
            cb(new AppError("Auth token cannot be generated. Please try again.", AppError.ErrorCode.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR));
        } else {
            console.info("MongoUser | Auth | Auth token for user was generated | " + JSON.stringify(obj));
            cb(null, obj);
        }
    });
};
```

the above code is doing the job, but the problem that I'm having is when pushing the new object, the new object doesn't gets returned in:

```
function(err,obj) {

}
```

Instead returns this:

```
{"n":1,"nModified":1,"ok":1}
```

What I want to know:

- Where Am I wrong?
- Am I doing this the right way? Any other way to $push the obj?

Thank You

Comment: `.update` returns number of modified documents, not the object

Comment: Please take a look. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31808786/mongoose-difference-of-findoneandupdate-and-update

Comment: @pk08 That's why I want to know, is there any other way to do this in order to get the updated part.

Comment: @Veeram That too, I've already checked it out. I want the updated part (in my case, the object I just pushed into my original doc) to be returned, not the whole doc.

Comment: Here you go.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35946989/how-to-get-back-the-new-value-after-an-update-in-a-embedded-array/35947329#35947329 You need to use projection with elemMatch to get the updated embedded object back.

Comment: @Veeram Thanks for the reply. This one looks interesting. I'll give this one a go. Doesn't much helps my original question though, as I want this to happen over DOCUMENT not SCHEMA

Comment: Np. Not sure what you mean with DOCUMENT not SCHEMA part  here The example over there is in mongodb query you've to convert it into mongoose.

Comment: @Veeram You are not getting the point. This is happening inside one of the Schema.method. Therefore, I already have the doc that I want to update. Your approach (and all others) want me to find the doc via the model and then execute findByIdAndUpdate. Now why'd I wanna do that if I already have the doc?

Comment: Sorry I'm not really familiar with mongoose. Why not just check the response `{"n":1,"nModified":1,"ok":1}` and return the `authAgent` back ? Its new entry and you just send that object which is what gets persist in database.

Comment: Whole doc. That is the main problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141777/discussion-between-veeram-and-ankitneo).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get back the new value after an update in a embedded array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35946989/how-to-get-back-the-new-value-after-an-update-in-a-embedded-array)

Comment: @KARTHIKEYAN.A Please read the comments above. Clearly stated, not MODEL, it's DOCUMENT. At least read the question carefully before marking it as a possible duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

[.update](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update) Only returns the modified number of documents

as    `{"n":1,"nModified":1,"ok":1}`

to return the modified documents you can use [findOneAndUpdate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndUpdate)

like `db.foo.findOneAndUpdate({class: 3}, {$set:{name: 231}}, {new: true})`

will return the response as

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58db5f4a611f51a2bf08bbb0"),
    "name" : "parwat",
    "class" : 3
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UserAccSchema.methods.generateAuthToken = function (authAgent, cb) {
    console.info("MongoUser | Auth | Attempting to generate auth token for user | " + this._id);
    this.findOneAndUpdate({_id: this._id}, {$set:{
            "meta.accessControl.authTokens": {
                authAgent: authAgent
            }}, {new: true}, function (err, obj) {
        if (err) {
            console.error("MongoUser | Auth | Error occurred while saving auth-token information | " + err);
            cb(new AppError("Auth token cannot be generated. Please try again.", AppError.ErrorCode.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR));
        } else {
            console.info("MongoUser | Auth | Auth token for user was generated | " + JSON.stringify(obj));
            cb(null, obj);
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: i assume your task is like that